# Maven profile activation based on classpath property

Tags: maven-profiles

Is it possible to activate a Maven profile based on a classpath property that you in turn set based on reading a properties file? I have verified that the classpath exists at the phase where my profile is supposed to take effect, and also separately gave the property through command line which worked, but when I attempt to read it from properties file, and attempt to run the profile based on classpath property, it does not work. I even tried setting the interested property as system property hoping that profile will be activated, but same result. [This link](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Activation) refers as if classpath properties can be read, but [this link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) mentions as if only system properties can be read for profile activation. However, for me both don't work. Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks,
Paddy